# Python Tkinter Label redrawing every 10 seconds

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, label

I have this following Python Tkinter code which redraw the label every 10 second. My question is , to me it seems like it is drawing the new label over and over again over the old label. So, eventually, after a few hours there will be hundreds of drawing overlapping (at least from what i understand). Will this use more memory or cause problem?

```
import Tkinter as tk
import threading

def Draw():
    frame=tk.Frame(root,width=100,height=100,relief='solid',bd=1)
    frame.place(x=10,y=10)
    text=tk.Label(frame,text='HELLO')
    text.pack()

def Refresher():
    print 'refreshing'
    Draw()
    threading.Timer(10, Refresher).start()

root=tk.Tk()
Refresher()
root.mainloop()
```

Here in my example, i am just using a single label.I am aware that i can use `textvariable` to update the text of the label or even `text.config`. But what am actually doing is to refresh a grid of label(like a table)+buttons and stuffs to match with the latest data available.

From my beginner understanding, if i wrote this `Draw()` function as class, i can destroy the `frame` by using `frame.destroy` whenever i execute `Refresher` function. But the code i currently have is written in functions without class ( i don't wish to rewrite the whole code into class).

The other option i can think of is to declare `frame` in the `Draw()` as global  and use `frame.destroy()` ( which i reluctant to do as this could cause name conflict if i have too many frames (which i do))

If overdrawing over the old drawing doesn't cause any problem (except that i can't see the old drawing), i can live with that.

These are all just my beginner thoughts. Should i destroy the frame before redraw the updated one? if so, in what way should i destroy it if the code structure is just like in my sample code? Or overdrawing the old label is fine?

**EDIT**

Someone mentioned that python tkinter is not thread safe and my code will likely to fail randomly.

I actually took [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223157/how-to-execute-a-function-asynchronously-every-60-seconds-in-python) as a reference to use `threading` as my solution and i didn't find anything about thread safety in that post.

I am wondering what are the general cases that i should not use `threading` and what are the general cases i could use `threading`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct way to run a function or update a label in tkinter is to use the [after](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method. This puts an event on the event queue to be executed at some time in the future. If you have a function that does some work, then puts itself back on the event queue, you have created something that will run forever.

Here's a quick example based on your example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

def Draw():
    global text

    frame=tk.Frame(root,width=100,height=100,relief='solid',bd=1)
    frame.place(x=10,y=10)
    text=tk.Label(frame,text='HELLO')
    text.pack()

def Refresher():
    global text
    text.configure(text=time.asctime())
    root.after(1000, Refresher) # every second...

root=tk.Tk()
Draw()
Refresher()
root.mainloop()
```

There are a lot of things I would change about that program from a coding style point of view, but I wanted to keep it as close to your original question as possible. The point is, you can use `after` to call a function that updates the label without having to create new labels. Plus, that function can arrange for itself to be called again at some interval. In this example I picked one second just so that the effect is easier to see.

You also asked "I am wondering what are the general cases that i should not use threading and what are the general cases i could use threading?"

To put a blunt point on it, you should never use threading if you have to ask a question about when to use threading. Threading is an advanced technique, it is complicated, and it easy to get wrong. It's quite possible for threading to make your program slower rather than faster. It has subtle consequences, such as your programs failing mysteriously if you do things that aren't thread safe.

To be more specific to your situation: you should avoid using threads with tkinter. You *can* use them, but you can't access widgets from these other threads. If you need to do something with a widget, you must put an instruction in a thread-safe queue, and then in the main thread you need to periodically check that queue to see if there's an instruction to be processed. There are examples of that on this website if you search for them.

If all that sounds complicated, it is. For most of the GUIs you write, you won't need to worry about that. If you can take large processes and break them down into chunks that execute in 100 ms or less, you only need `after`, and never need threads.

Answer (score 6):

To allow the cleanup with minimal code changes, you could pass previous frames explicitly:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def Draw(oldframe=None):
    frame = tk.Frame(root,width=100,height=100,relief='solid',bd=1)
    frame.place(x=10,y=10)
    tk.Label(frame, text='HELLO').pack()
    frame.pack()
    if oldframe is not None:
        oldframe.destroy() # cleanup
    return frame

def Refresher(frame=None):
    print 'refreshing'
    frame = Draw(frame)
    frame.after(10000, Refresher, frame) # refresh in 10 seconds

root = tk.Tk()
Refresher()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: will the `.after` method compromise the functionality of the rest of the program? i mean will the rest of the program wait until the refresher function? The other thing is what does `oldframe` represent exactly?

Comment: `.after` returns immediately. It just schedules the `Refresher()` function to be run later in the GUI thread. `Refresher()` should not contain any blocking calls e.g., network requests. `oldframe` is the previous value returned by `Draw()`.