# Error while trying to change tkinter label from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I have thread1. and a main GUI thread. I am trying to change a label on the GUI thread, form the thread1. I pass the variable of the label on the thread as an argument. But I get the following error:

> UnpickleableError: Cannot pickle  objects

How can I change GUI elements outside the main GUI Thread/Class

```
class MyFirstGUI:
    communicationQueue=Queue()
    def __init__(self, master):
      thisLabel = Label(master, text="Test")
      thisLabel.pack()
      tempThread=testThread(thisLabel)
      tempThread.start()

class testThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, label):
      label["text"]="something"
```

Comment: Please add code snippets so we can actually see the code

Comment: I added the code just for you my friend :)

Comment: related [Python Tkinter Label redrawing every 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17847869/4279)

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading, random, time

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
      self.label = tk.Label(master, text = "Test")
      self.label.pack()

    def update(self):
        while True:
            self.label["text"] = random.randint(1, 1000)
            time.sleep(1)


root = tk.Tk()

GUI = MyFirstGUI(root)

loop = threading.Thread(target = GUI.update).start()

root.mainloop()
```

I think this is what you are asking for.