# How to make tkinter constantly update a widget based on external data?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making an app that needs to constantly update based on changing data from an external source. In my prototype version I will read text from a file. The python code below displays the first line of the text file.

```
from tkinter import Label
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
root.resizable(False,False)

class widgets():
    def __init__(self, root):
    
        self.labl = Label(root, text="")
        self.labl.pack()
    
        status = self.get_status()
        self.labl.config(text = status)         
    
    def get_status(self):
        file = open('status.txt')
        status = file.readline()             
        file.close()
        return status
    
widgets(root)
root.mainloop()
```

How do I fix it so the Label above is updated soon after a change to the text file is saved?

Comment: I've removed the duplicate text from the question. What is your original external source? A socket, or file or something else?

Comment: This original source is another python function my coworker is writing. We are controlling a robot with a Raspberry Pi, and the data gives different types of status of the robot.

Comment: I'd probably use other thread for checking the data, maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934144/update-data-in-a-tkinter-gui-with-data-from-a-second-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter, like many GUI toolkits, has a continuously running loop that pulls an event off of a queue and the processes any code associated with that event. One way to add something to the queue is with the method `after`. It takes a number of milliseconds to delay, and then a callable to call at some point after the delay.

You can create a function that gets the data, updates the UI, and then adds itself back onto the queue. This will work fine if the time it takes to get the data is only a couple hundred milliseconds or so. If it goes much more than that you'll want to use multithreading or multiprocessing so as not to have a laggy UI.

Here's a simple example starting with your code, though I fixed a couple of poor programming practices (no need to import Label since you're importing the module, class name should begin with uppercase)

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
root.resizable(False,False)

class Widgets():
    def __init__(self, root):

        self.labl = tk.Label(root, text="")
        self.labl.pack()

        self.update_status()

    def update_status(self):
        status = self.get_status()
        self.labl.config(text = status)
        self.labl.after(1000, self.update_status)

    def get_status(self):
        file = open('status.txt')
        status = file.readline()
        file.close()
        return status

Widgets(root)
root.mainloop()
```

In this example, once you call `self.update_label()` once, it will update the label and then schedule itself to run again in one second (1000ms), and will do so until the program exits.